# Filling pandas column with range of numbers based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to fill in a column with numbers -5000 to 5004, stepping by 4, between a condition in one column and a condition in another. The count starts when `start==1`. The count won't always get to `5004`, so it needs to stop when `end==1`

Here is a example of the input:

```
start  end
1      0
0      0
0      0
0      0
0      0
0      1
0      0
0      0
1      0
0      0
```

I have tried `np.arange`:

```
df['time'] = df['start'].apply(lambda x: np.arange(-5000,5004,4) if x==1 else 0)
```

This obviously doesn't work - I ended up with a series in one cell. I also messed around with `cycle` from `itertools`, but that doesn't work because the distances between the start and end aren't always equal. I also feel there might be a way to do this with `ffill`:

```
rise = df[df.start.where(df.start==1).ffill(limit=1250).notnull()]
```

Not sure how to edit this to stop at the correct place though.

I'd love to have a lambda function that achieves this, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is my expected output:

```
start  end  time
1      0    -5000
0      0    -4996
0      0    -4992
0      0    -4988
0      0    -4984
0      1    -4980
0      0     nan
0      0     nan
1      0    -5000
0      0    -4996
```

Comment: Kindly add your expected output dataframe

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
grouping = df['start'].add(df['end'].shift(1).fillna(0)).cumsum()
df['time'] = (df.groupby(grouping).cumcount() * 4 - 5000)
df.loc[df.groupby(grouping).filter(lambda x: x[['start', 'end']].sum().sum() == 0).index, 'time'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   start  end    time
0      1    0 -5000.0
1      0    0 -4996.0
2      0    0 -4992.0
3      0    0 -4988.0
4      0    0 -4984.0
5      0    1 -4980.0
6      0    0     NaN
7      0    0     NaN
8      1    0 -5000.0
9      0    0 -4996.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much- this is exactly what I needed